# ubuntu sudo apt --fix-broken install fails "Unable to make backup symlink"

Tags: apt, package-management

Trying to fix a broken install:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container
The following packages will be upgraded:
  systemd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 128 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2903 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 34600 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_237-3ubuntu10.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (237-3ubuntu10.25) over (237-3ubuntu10.17) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_237-3ubuntu10.25_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup symlink for './usr/share/man/man8/systemd-sysusers.service.8.gz': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_237-3ubuntu10.25_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$ ls ./usr/share/man/man8/systemd-sysusers.service.8.gz
    ./usr/share/man/man8/systemd-sysusers.service.8.gz
```

The file that the error message complains about is there.  What can I do to get around this problem?

Update: more details:

```
ls -ll ./usr/share/man/man8/systemd-sysusers.service.8.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jerryb jerryb 0 Aug 19 13:05 ./usr/share/man/man8/systemd-sysusers.service.8.gz
```

Update 2:

After apply the steps given below, I tried again.  This time I got

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_237-3ubuntu10.25_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup symlink for './usr/share/man/man8/systemd-timedated.8.gz': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while p
rocessing:
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and the output of ls for that one:

```
ls -ll ./usr/share/man/man8/systemd-timedated.8.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Aug 19 14:25 ./usr/share/man/man8/systemd-timedated.8.gz -> /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-timedated.8.gz
```

Comment: I updated the original post with that info

Comment: OK, that got me to another problem (see update)

Comment: There were tons of them.  I deleted the lot, ran the fix-broken and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I found many symlinks pointing to ''.  I deleted them all and the command finished successfully.